# MVC2 MySQL Hosting Issue?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an MVC2 app that utilizes MySql.Web ver. 6.2.2.0, on my dev machine locally it works fine!

However, once I upload it to my http://www.winhost.com account I get the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: Unable to initialize provider.  Missing or incorrect schema.
Line 32:         <clear/>
Line 33:         <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
Line 34:              type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider,MySql.Web,   
Version=6.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
```

Is there something I can do to get this going? Or am I at the mercy of my host?

here is my config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
         type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider,MySql.Web, Version=6.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
         autogenerateschema="true"
         connectionStringName="mysql"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         passwordFormat="Encrypted"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
         applicationName="/"
 />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: I would like to add using version 6.3.5 of MySql connector fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these articles to help ensure your host, your MySQL instance, and your web app are configured correctly.

- [MySQL ASP.NET Membership and Role Provider](http://blog.nolanbailey.com/2008/03/08/mysql-aspnet-membership-and-role-provider/194)
- [ASP.NET and MySQL - membership provider](http://blog.webunusual.com/2008/08/aspnet-and-mysql-membership-provider_05.html)
- [Marvin Palmer has a great walkthrough on Implementing .NET Membership and Roles using MySql Connector](http://www.marvinpalmer.com/MarvinPalmer/post/Implement-NET-Membership-and-Roles-using-MySql-Connector-523-on-GoDaddy.aspx)
- [Another potentially related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393131/unable-to-initialize-provider-missing-or-incorrect-schema-for-mysql-web-connec).

Comment: @Jreeter: Thanks! I didn't intend any funny or humor though :)